# Почему выходит ошибка? ValueError. Много чего пробовал, не уходит

Tags: python

```
with open("graf.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        data = line.split()
        n = data[0]
        n = int(n)
        e = data[1]
        e = int(e)

    v = [[0]*n for i in range(n)]
    for i in range(e):
        r, c = map(int, input())
    v[r-1][c-1] = v[c-1][r-1] = 1
    for s in v:
        k = sum(s)
    print(k)
```

В строке `n = int(n)` пишет ошибку, пробовал `.strip()`, не помогло. В дебагере смотрел, e нормально перевелась в int, а n не может никак
В чем дело?

Файл:

```
966 145
531 404
754 631
738 80
331 394
424 248
```

Comment: приведенные данные такую ошибку не вызывают. Кстати, текст ошибки нужно полностью копировать в вопрос

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'п»ї1000'
это пишет

Comment: теперь посмотри внимательно на "файл" в вопросе и найди там строчку из комментария. Таких данных там нет. А заодно ответь для себя на вопрос - а что собственно должно произойти в случае ``int('п»ї1000')``?

Comment: В файле 5к строк, зачем мне все сюда пихать
В файле 1000 это первая строка 1 столбец

Comment: Незачем, конечно, сюда пихать 5к строк. Но из ошибки ясно видно, что данные в файле не всегда такие, как приведены в вопросе. И понятно в чем причина ошибки

Comment: Так причина в чём?

Comment: как только получится ответить на вопрос "что собственно должно произойти в случае ``int('п»ї1000')``", то сразу станет понятно :) Что делает эта конструкция?

Comment: Можете кратко ответить, как исправить код и где? Я ничего не понимаю

Comment: Нет, я не могу ответить кратко, т.к. я не знаю, что это код должен делать и какие там данные. Если понимаете, что делает функция int(), которую вы используете, то проблем с пониманием почему возникла ошибка вообще не должно быть.

Comment: Файл в кодировке UTF-8 c BOM (это три хитрых символа в самом начале  файла и есть).  `open("graf.txt", "r", encoding="utf_8_sig") `  Ну или можно сохранить файл в любой кодировке без BOM